# OCaml - This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int

Tags: int, ocaml

Why am i getting this error if I'm using truncate, which should cast the float to an int? It takes in a list of ints.

```
let find_closest bi =
    let bi_integer = (car bi) in 
    truncate (floor ((log bi_integer)/(log 2)))
```

Comment: what are ``car``, ``truncate``, ``floor``, ``log``?

Comment: arent truncate, floor, and log built into the language? car is set to List.hd

Comment: sorry. i did not notice that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(float_of_int bi_integer)` instead of just `bi_integer`. Also use `/.` instead of `/` and use `2.0` instead of `2`--OCaml has no implicit conversions among types.